# Does Notepad++ have a blocking mode?

Tags: notepad++

I have command-line tools that sometimes need to bring up a file in an external editor to let me edit it. These tools rely on the blocking behavior of editors: once the editor program exits, they expect the file to have been modified and saved.

However, that's not how Notepad++ seems to work. When you launch Notepad++ from the command line, its command-line invocation immediately returns, even though the Notepad++ GUI just launched. This contrasts with, say, Notepad, for which the command-line invocation returns only when the window is closed.

Is there a way to block the Notepad++ command-line invocation until I close the file it opened?

Comment: Did you tried `Process.Exited` event? may this help you in some way.

Comment: Notepad doesn't block normally. How are you launching it that makes it do so? (I use Notepad frequently from a command prompt, and it never blocks using `notepad somefile.txt`.)

Comment: @KenWhite, that's not the correct explanation indeed. The calling tool seems to wait until the program exits, which works for Notepad but not Notepad++ because the program instance just calls to the already existing one and says "hey, open that up for me please".

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/908664/have-the-command-prompt-launch-an-application-like-notepad-and-block-until-it-is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it's been determined that the tool waits until the program exits, creating a new NP++ instance does the trick. Since this is just for a quick edit, I found it useful to also tell NP++ to ignore any previous session and to hide the tab bar.

```
set EDITOR="path\to\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession -notabbar
```

I found the list of options [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches).

Comment: The `-notabbar` (or "No tab bar") option is not required. On older versions of NPP this will toggle `Settings > Preferences > General > Tab Bar > Hide` globally (despite the `-nosession` parameter). On v7.7.1 this works correctly. Notepad++ will still need to be closed to unblock the command line call. Since toggling the tab bar is irrelevant to the question, recommend just the `-multiInst -nosession` parameters only.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "nosession" and "multiInst"... the docs are little help

Comment: -multiInst: Launch another Notepad++ instance, so user can have several Notepad++ simultaneously.


-nosession: Launch Notepad++ without previous session.


[source](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/)